# Gl3w Python script errors: how to solve it/get it working

Tags: python, windows

So after almost 2 days of not being able to get GLEW working: trying Gl3w.

The python script is complaining about Syntax Errors, said all the prints signaled a syntax error, so I removed them all. Now it's complaining about the imports... (basically it seems it's complaining of the entire code)

I don't know Python, but I can't find support for Gl3w... should I keep trying to "correct the script", which I think should be working fine? What am I "doing wrong"?

Thanks!

This is the script: https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w

Comment: Pro tip: Always include the *full* traceback when you have a problem with Python.

Comment: Full traceback meaning? Sorry, I've never dealt with Python, just thought of opening up and trying to fix it myself since I could read it with notepad.
But by full traceback you mean?

Comment: The part where it tells you the file, line number and the exact line with the `SyntaxError` message. I've included one in my answer. For other exceptions it'll state `Traceback` at the top.

Comment: Oh, ok, in the future if I deal with python issues again, I will.

Comment: In this case, the problem is common enough and I recognized it from your description, but by including the full error message you save us from having to guess.

Comment: I thought of that, but since the script only showed the error for a fraction of second (immediate close), I just kept enter pressed to open it several times and read little by little.

Comment: Right, this is windows and I keep forgetting the console helpfully closes.. you can run the script from the console too (open CMD.exe, cd to the folder with the script, and run `python gl3w_gen.py` or similar (is there a `python2.7`? Use the full path to the exe if you have to).

Comment: Yeah, hadn't thought of that, not used to using CMD in windows, only in linux. Also in case you don't know, saving the hassle of cd'ing folders: you can shift+right click to "Open command window here"

Comment: Note: you should be using the repo on https://github.com/shakesoda/gl3w, not the old one from skaslev. The new one uses the more up-to-date glcorearb.h header to generate its stuff.

Comment: Oh, nice, thank you @Nicol Bolas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 3, while the script requires Python 2:

> Its main part is a simple `gl3w_gen.py` Python 2.6 script

In python 2, print is a statement, in 3, it's a function. This difference leads to syntax errors when trying to run python 2 code with python 3:

```
$ python3.3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 08:16:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'Hello world!'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 'Hello world!'
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks man! Not knowing of python I just got the latest, had no idea it needed a specific version, despite the script saying it's a 2.6 script.

Comment: 2.7 will most likely do, get it [here](http://python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/).

Comment: Yes, I've already gotten it and got gl3w script working. Thanks again, will accept as soon as it is possible :)